# History of terms type 1 error and type 2 error?

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors, history

The terms "type I" (or "alpha) and "type II" (or "beta) error, to denote false positive and false negative, are often used. What is the history of those terms?

Answer (score 4):

Neyman and Pearson were the pioneers in formulating the integral framework of the modern theory of hypothesis testing that we are acquainted with. While I cannot assert with absolute certainty, it is plausible their works were instrumental in developing or, for the matter, popularising the nomenclatures in question.

From [I]:

[image]

From [II]:

[image]

From [III]:

[image]

---

### References:

[I] *J. NEYMAN, PH.D, E. S. PEARSON, D.Sc*, ON THE USE AND INTERPRETATION OF CERTAIN TEST CRITERIA FOR PURPOSES OF STATISTICAL INFERENCE PART I, Biometrika, Volume 20A, Issue 1-2, December 1928, Pages 175–240, https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/20A.1-2.175.

[II] IX. On the problem of the most efficient tests of statistical hypotheses,
*Jerzy Neyman, Egon Sharpe Pearson*, 16 February 1933, https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.1933.0009.

[III] *Neyman, J., & Pearson, E.* (1933). The testing of statistical hypotheses in relation to probabilities a priori. Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 29(4), 492-510. doi:10.1017/S030500410001152X.

Comment: Yep, Miller's list -- https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/t/ agrees, citing David (1995)  (which would be David, H. A. (1995), "First (?) Occurrence of Common Terms in Mathematical Statistics," *The American Statistician*, **49**, 121-133; there's also a 1998 update by David in the same journal)

Comment: Very well, thanks, for pointing that out @Glen_b.

Comment: Calling these "errors" has resulted in a hundred years of unclear thinking.  They are not error probabilities but merely assertion trigger probabilities.  For a full explanation see https://hbiostat.org/bbr/alpha.html.  What's needed is the probability of a _decision error_ which has nothing to do with $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: I agree. That is unfortunate @FrankHarrell. I have come across rather mild discontentment from various authors: traditionally "non-mnemonic" as written by Casella, Berger; Lehmann seldom used the two terms in his treatise. But the tradition is deeply rooted.